# Pull data jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to print pull the text of "10 - 50" using jsoup but I can't seem to pull it correctly. Here's the HTML code:

```
 <dd>
        <time itemprop="datePublished">21 October 2012</time>
       </dd>
       <dt>
        Current Version:
       </dt>
       <dd itemprop="softwareVersion">
        1.0
       </dd>
       <dt itemprop="operatingSystems" content="Android">
        Requires Android:
       </dt>
       <dd>
        2.3.3 and up
       </dd>
       <dt>
        Category:
       </dt>
       <dd>
        <a href="xxx">Entertainment</a>
       </dd>
       <dt>
        Installs:
       </dt>
       <dd itemprop="numDownloads">
        10 - 50
        <div class="normalized-daily-installs-chart" style="width: 105px;">
         <img src="xxx" />
         <p>last 30 days</p>
        </div>
       </dd>
       <dt>
        Size:
       </dt>
       <dd itemprop="fileSize">
        12M
       </dd>
```

I've tried this code but it prints "1.0 10 - 50 last 30 days 12M €0.69 Everyone"

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class googletest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect("private url"
                        )
                .get();
        Elements spans = doc.select("dd[itemprop]");
        System.out.println(spans.text());

    }

}
```

I simply just want to print the string 10 - 50 by itself no other values, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues.  First, you need strengthen your select expression so that it only returns elements where itemprop is equal to numDownloads  ex `[itemprop=numDownloads]`  Now your `spans` variable should have a collection of Elements with just one Element.  You can access this element using  `spans.first()`  Once you have a single element you can use the `ownText()` method to return the text that is a direct child of the element (avoiding the text of any other child elements).

```
public class googletest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect("private url"
                        )
                .get();
        Elements spans = doc.select("dd[itemprop=numDownloads]");
        System.out.println(spans.first().ownText());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
Element dts = doc.select("dd[itemprop]").get(0);
   System.out.println(dts.text());
```